# Element Range Index & availability for search

Tags: indexing, marklogic

MarkLogic 9.0.8.2

We have around 20M records in our database in XML format.

To work with facets, we have created element-rage-index on the given element.

It is working fine, so no issue there.

Real problem is that, we now want to deploy same code on different environments like System Test(ST), UAT, Production.

Before deploying code, we have to make sure that given index exist. So we execute it in 1/2 days in advance.

We noticed that until full indexing is completed, we can't deploy our code else it will start showing up errors like this.

```
    <error:code>XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND</error:code>
    <error:name/>
    <error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version>
    <error:message>No element range index</error:message>
    <error:format-string>XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: cts:element-reference(fn:QName("","tc"), ("type=string", "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/")) -- No string element range index for tc collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/ </error:format-string>
```

And once index is finished, same code will run as expected.

Specially in ST/UAT, we are fine if we get partial data with unfinished indexing.

Is there any way we can achieve this? else we are loosing too much time just to wait for index to finish.

[image]

This happens every time when we come up with new feature which has dependency on new index

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the reindexer throttle?

Answer (score 5):

You can only use a range index if it exists and is available. It is not available until all matching records have been indexed.

You should create your indexes earlier and allow enough time to finish reindexing before deploying code that uses them. Maybe make your code deployment depend upon the reindexing status and not allow for it to be deployed until it has completed.

If the new versions of your applications can function without the indexes (value query instead of range-query), or you are fine with queries returning inaccurate results, then you could enable/disable the section of code utilizing them with feature flags, or wrap with `try/catch`, but you really should just create the indexes earlier in your deployment cycles.

Otherwise, if you are performing tests without a complete and functioning environment, what are you really testing?

Comment: Hello Mads Hansen, Thanks for your reply, ok, understood. We are also deploying new features/bugs which does not have dependency on index to be completed, So by the time, index is completed, testing team execute test for other scenarios.

Comment: To complete indexing faster, suppose we have to create 3 indexes, should we create each index separately or we create them together  ? or it does not matter?

Comment: If a doc has content matching the index it will need to be reindexed, so it’s more efficient to do that work once to re-save the doc.

Comment: Hello MH, Thanks for your reply, i mean if we have around 2/3 new features and all required indexing, then better to create 1 index, once it is completed, create new one OR create all at once and wait for all to be completed?

Comment: How about reducing the number of documents in your test databases? Do you need to have 20M documents in each of those? Less documents means quicker indexing so that could be a solution for your challenge, as well...

Comment: Hello Sasam, Thanks for your reply & suggestions. Yes that will help for test environment.

Comment: Hello @MadsHansen, can you please reply to my question?